# RF22 library for Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: pi-pico, communication, radio

I want to use [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10153) RF22 module (in a breakout board) with a Raspberry Pi Pico. However, I have tried both the [RadioHead](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/RadioHead/blob/master/RH_RF22.h) (which is for teensy boards, as i found out later) and [RF22](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RF22/) library without any success. The code cannot be compiled for Raspberry Pi Pico. Do you have any other libraries to suggest that I could use?

Answer (score 2):

This is a working library: https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/

I had the modified library installed that is compatible with [Teensy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems#Software-compatibility_only) boards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In addition to the Community Bot's comment above, I'd like to encourage you to provide a brief description of your development environment; i.e. are you using the default RPi 4, or macOS, or Windows, or Linux, or...?

Comment: I am using windows, i am writing code on arduino IDE with the [arduino-pico core](https://arduino-pico.readthedocs.io/en/latest/help.html), and i am using the  raspberry pi pico h 2021. As for documentation,  the links provide the necessary details.